# How to Autosize Column Width in .CSHTML?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2013

So in MVC I used the power of VS2013 to autogenerate a view off a list type which displays the list of objects and its properties in array format using foreach. How can modify the code to auto-size the column widths to fit?

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th align="center">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsoCode)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th align="center">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Continent)
        </th>
        <th align="center">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CountryId)
        </th>
        <th align="center">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TotalLanguages)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td align ="center">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsoCode)
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td align ="center">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Continent)
        </td>
        <td align ="center">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CountryId)
        </td>
        <td align ="center">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalLanguages)
        </td>
        <td>
            @*@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |*@
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.CountryId })
            @*@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })*@
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: using T4 you can do it during the generation. If I understood well.

Comment: Autosize columns to fit what exactly?

Comment: The contents of the table cells

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make sure there's enough space to show all the content in the table cells. If you are giving an explicit width to the table (e.g. using pixels as measurement units) you might be inadvertently restricting the space allowed for tbe table to render its contents. Here's what you can try

- if an explicit width its set for the table or cells then remove it or use dynamic units such as percentage
- set `white-space` `nowrap` for the table cells

Give it a  go and see how it goes

Comment: I tried:             
`<td style="white-space:nowrap">
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
</td>` 
but it didn't auto-size it to make it smaller

Comment: Ended up having to go into bootstrap and commented out the width: 100%; line in .table as well

Comment: Worked for me. <td nowrap="">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</td>